# How to update the edited item of knockout js observablearray in UI part?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

How to update the knockout js observablearray in UI part..Initially Im editing a item and in update function i'm trying to update a particular item so im sending the current item object to service and getting the updated vales as response. Inside the response I need to update the observablearray as well the UI too.. I have tried some thing like this and its not working for me...  please check in http://jsfiddle.net/up8rB/20/

```
<div data-bind="ifnot: Role()">           
 <label for="description">Description</label>
 <input type="text" data-bind="value: Description" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the description..." />
 <button data-bind="click: $root.create"> Create</button>
</div>
<div data-bind="if: Role">
 <label for="description">Description</label>
 <input type="text" data-bind="value: Role().Description" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the description..." />
 <button data-bind="click: $root.update"> Save</button>
</div>
<table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped" data-bind="visible: Roles().length > 0">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>RoleID</th>
<th>Description</th>                               
<th>Actions</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: Roles">
<tr>
<td data-bind="text: $data.RoleID"></td>
<td data-bind="text: $data.Description"></td>
<td>
<button data-bind="click: $root.edit" >Edit</button>
<button data-bind="click: $root.delete" >Delete</button>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
function RoleViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.RoleID = ko.observable("0");
    self.Description = ko.observable().extend({
        required: { message: 'Please supply description ..' }
    });

var Role = {
    RoleID: self.RoleID,
    Description: self.Description
};
self.Role = ko.observable();
self.Roles = ko.observableArray();
$.ajax({
        url: 'Service.svc/RoleCollection',
        cache: false,
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: {},
        success: function (data) {
            self.Roles(data); //Put the response in ObservableArray
        }
    });
self.edit = function (Role) {
    self.Role(Role);
}
self.update = function () {
        var Role = self.Role();
        $.ajax({
            url: '..service.svc/UpdateRole',
            cache: false,
            type: 'PUT',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: ko.toJSON(Role),
            success: function (data) {
                for (var i = 0; i < self.Roles().length; i++) {
                    alert(self.Roles()[i].RoleID());
                    if (self.Roles()[i].RoleID() === data.RoleID) {
                        self.Role(self.Roles()[i]);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        })
}
var viewModel = new RoleViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Comment: Are you getting valid data back? How is it not working?

Comment: @gfish3000 Yes Im getting the valid data as response... but something stuck inside the loop.. even i didt get any alert inside the "for loop"..

Comment: You'll have to post more information.  For example: I can't see where you're putting anything into Roles, meaning your observable array length is always zero, and you'll never see your alert because you never enter the for loop.  Are you able to post a jsfiddle?

Comment: @Paul Now I have edited the code part in question please check and tel me...

Comment: What does the HTML look like?  How are you driving your model?  How are you invoking the update?

Comment: @Paul I have added the whole code please check .... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that your are assigning items to your `observable array` that aren't themselves `observable`, so your `UI` is not updating when they change.

I did some renaming, as I found it confusing with so many things named `'Role'`, but the first change was your array setup:

```
var roles = [{
    RoleID: ko.observable(1),
    Description: ko.observable('First item')
}, {
    RoleID: ko.observable(2),
    Description: ko.observable('Second item')
}];
```

I also modified the update function:

```
self.update = function () {
    var _Role = self.Role();
    for (var i = 0; i < self.Roles().length; i++) {
        if (self.Roles()[i].RoleID === _Role.RoleID) {
            self.Roles()[i] = _Role();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

See the **[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/up8rB/30/)**

**Update:**

Your `json` response should populate the `observableArray` correclty, but you may have an issue when setting it back after the update, try setting the properties rather than overwriting the element:

```
self.update = function () {
    var _Role = self.Role();
    for (var i = 0; i < self.Roles().length; i++) {
        if (self.Roles()[i].RoleID === _Role.RoleID) {
            self.Roles()[i].RoleID = _Role().RoleID;
            self.Roles()[i].Description = _Role().Description;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

See the **[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/up8rB/31/)**

Comment: if im clcik edit and made change in text and then i click on delete button value get changed its not a right one!! it should update when i click on save button....

Comment: observables will update on loss of focus, which is what is happening in this sample. the delete button isn't doing anything other than changing the focus, so perhaps just change your save method to clear/reset the selected item instead and let the observable manage the item edit.